# Disable javascript in frame

Tags: iframe

How I can disable javascript codes from iframe:

```
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;display:none" src="http://page.pl/" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

*Is it possible?*

I can't do it by PHP (using `file_get_contents()` and `regex`) because web page from iframe must create a cookies into visitor's browser.

Answer (score 0):

This may give you a starting point. Basically if you look at [enter link CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) when you switch from View mode to Source mode.  You can see when you enter a sample of javascript code and switch to source code, it will make encoded string which disable the java script execution. 
Let me know if you want to see the implementation details of the javascript string encoding.

Comment: That's fine. How I can encode javascript code into iframe ?

Comment: Sorry for late response, is this page  http://page.pl  is yours or an external page which you load into iframe and it has its own java script code ?